# Connecting via Swarm

Tags: foursquare

I was hoping that my app would be able to authenticate and connect via Swarm, for the case of users who have Swarm but not Foursquare (my nominal situation).  But when my app tries to authenticate, it expects the Foursquare app to be there too.  Any chance this will change, or do I need to require my app users to have both (since the app requires they have Swarm)?

Answer (score 0):

Foursquare and Swarm share account credentials so it shouldn't matter if you have a "Connect with Foursquare" or "Connect with Swarm" button. Check out the [guide on connecting](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) - you shouldn't need either Foursquare or Swarm installed to generate an OAuth token.

Also, have you checked out the utility classes Foursquare provides for connecting on [iOS](https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-ios-oauth/) and [Android](https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth)? They do lots of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Yes. Your 2nd paragraph is the reason for my question.  Obviously I could use oAuth, but since i know my users have Swarm , I want to use the utility classes.  But they seem to require Foursquare to be installed skiing with Swarm for some reason.

Comment: I tested the utility class for iOS without Foursquare or Swarm installed and it opened up the OAuth webview prompting me to login with my Foursquare or Swarm credentials. What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: I am using FoursquareOAuth.getConnectIntent(), and if Foursquare and Swarm are installed, it works fine (doesn't open any webview - creates an intent to the Foursquare app authentication).  If I have Swarm installed and not Foursquare, it takes me to the Google Play store to install Foursquare.  This is actually the documented behavior.  My post was to request that this work if Swarm is installed without Foursquare.